# li .sibling .fadeTo issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having issues with getting the siblings of my footer navbar to fade their opacity when $(this) is hovered over. I tried to do this with jQuery, and it works...but not very smoothly. If you hover the mouse from icon to icon they start blinking and flashing in a manner that I don't want them to.

There must be a smoother and easier way to do this that works....

To better explain, here is a jSfiddle I did with the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/h48ay6es/

And here is my source code for the jQuery I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.footerLinks li').hover(
    function() {
    $(this).siblings().fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    },
    function() {
    $(this).siblings().fadeTo(500, 1.0)
    }
 )
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.footerLinks li').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    },
    function() {
      $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(500, 1.0)
    }
  )
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h48ay6es/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.footerLinks {
  text-align: center;
}

.footerLinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
.footerLinks li:hover {
  opacity:0.4;
}

.footerLinks img {
  max-width: 40px;
}

.footerNav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="footerLinks">
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/CODAWORLD/"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/facebook_online_social_media-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/CODA_world"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/online_social_media_twitter-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/coda_world/"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/instagram_online_social_media-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/codaworlddancecrew"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/youtube_online_social_media-128.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

I liked the "stop()" answer and would up vote that but when I look at the links when passing the mouse over each social icon it still does not look right.  Perhaps a delay or something like that.

In this solution I remove the javascript and just use CSS transition on the opacity property.  I think css is a better tool for the job if that is allowed in the requirements.  Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is wanting all the icons that are not the one being hovered over to be faded. Your example fades the one being hovered over. For instance if hovered over twitter, then facebook, instagram, and youtube should be faded.

Comment: Your are correct I misinterpreted the results that were asked for.  Hopefully my response will still be helpful.